# Builder - A 2D Minecraft clone

Tags: python, game, python-2.x, pygame, minecraft

I was poking around on my Raspberry Pi that I hadn't turned on or used in a while, and I stumbled upon this Python script that I wrote ~1.5 years ago, and I was intrigued.

Essentially, it's a 2D [Minecraft](https://minecraft.net) clone with no concept of survival. It does have a slightly, complex control scheme, so here's a list of buttons that can be used, and what they do:

- <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> - Move left/right through the world.
- <kbd>LMB</kbd> - Place a tile at the desired position.
- <kbd>RMB</kbd> - Destroy a tile at the desired position.
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>/<kbd>SPACE</kbd> - Change the currently selected tile.
- <kbd>q</kbd> - Switch to the underground "realm".
- <kbd>e</kbd> - Switch to the above ground "realm".

Even though I wrote this quite a while ago, and if I had written it now, it would have looked better, I'm still curious as to what all can be improved.

```
#!usr/bin/env python
# Basic 2d building game, Builder
import pygame
import random
import shutil
import time
import math
import sys
import os


debug_game_data = int(sys.argv[1])
current_version = "0.5.0"

WIDTH = 700
HEIGHT = 700

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Builder {}".format(current_version))
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace.ttf", 13)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos
key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed

mouse_x = 0
mouse_y = 1

TILE_SIZE = 25
round_tile_size = lambda x: (
    1+(x-1)/TILE_SIZE)*TILE_SIZE if x%TILE_SIZE>=10 else (
        x/TILE_SIZE)*TILE_SIZE


# Dictionary of game textures
TEXTURES = {
    "dirt": pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameDirtBlock.png"), (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)),
    "grass": pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameGrassBlock.png"), (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)),
    "stone": pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameStoneBlock.png"), (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)),
    "sand": pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameSandBlock.png"), (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)),
    "water": pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameWaterBlock.png"), (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)),
    "wood": pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameWoodBlock.png"), (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)),
    "leaf": pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameLeafBlock.png"), (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)),
}


# Lists containing tile data for overworld and underground
overworld_data = []
underground_data = []


# Variables concerning whether the player is underground, or aboveground
player_underground = False
player_aboveground = True


# Dictionary containing tile types
TILE_TYPES = {
    "dirt": 0,
    "grass": 1,
    "stone": 2,
    "sand": 3,
    "water": 4,
    "wood": 5,
    "leaf": 6
}


# Colors for the game
BLUE_LIGHT = (0, 0, 220)
GRAY_DARK = (100, 100, 100)
BLUE_DARK = (0, 0, 175)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)


# Background class, for rendering the day/night cycle
class Background(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.SKY_COLOR = BLUE_LIGHT
        self.UNDERGROUND_SKY_COLOR = GRAY_DARK

    # Render the background
    def render_background(self):
        if player_aboveground:
            screen.fill(self.SKY_COLOR)
        if player_underground:
            screen.fill(self.UNDERGROUND_SKY_COLOR)


# Tile class, to be used to create a chunk with the Chunk class
class Tile(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, tile_type, tile_image):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tile_type = tile_type
        self.tile_image = tile_image

    # Update the position of a tile
    def update_tile_position(self, x_change, y_change):
        self.x += x_change
        self.y += y_change

    # Render the tile on the screen
    def render_tile(self):
        screen.blit(self.tile_image, (self.x, self.y))


# Chunk class, for generating a chunk and rendering it
class Chunk(object):
    def __init__(self, chunk_x):
        self.chunk_x = chunk_x
        self.chunk_data_overworld = []
        self.chunk_data_underground = []

    # Generate an overworld chunk for the center
    def generate_overworld_chunk_center(self):

        # Generate the stone section
        stone_end = HEIGHT-round_tile_size(random.randint(3, 4)*TILE_SIZE)
        for y in range(HEIGHT, stone_end, -TILE_SIZE):
            self.chunk_data_overworld.append(Tile(self.chunk_x, y,
                TILE_TYPES["stone"], TEXTURES["stone"]))

        # Generate the dirt section
        dirt_end = stone_end-round_tile_size(random.randint(1, 2)*TILE_SIZE)
        for y in range(stone_end, dirt_end, -TILE_SIZE):
            self.chunk_data_overworld.append(Tile(self.chunk_x, y,
                TILE_TYPES["dirt"], TEXTURES["dirt"]))

        # Generate the grass section
        grass_end = dirt_end-round_tile_size(TILE_SIZE)
        for y in range(dirt_end, grass_end, -TILE_SIZE):
            self.chunk_data_overworld.append(Tile(self.chunk_x, y,
                TILE_TYPES["grass"], TEXTURES["grass"]))

        # Generate a tree based on a probability
        value1 = random.random()*random.randint(1, 10)
        value2 = random.random()*random.randint(1, 10)
        value3 = random.random()*random.randint(1, 10)
        if value1 < value2 < value3:

            # Generate the wood section
            tree_end = grass_end-round_tile_size(random.randint(4, 5)*TILE_SIZE)
            for y in range(grass_end, tree_end, -TILE_SIZE):
                self.chunk_data_overworld.append(Tile(self.chunk_x, y,
                    TILE_TYPES["wood"], TEXTURES["wood"]))

            # Generate the leaf section
            leaf_end = tree_end-round_tile_size(random.randint(1, 2)*TILE_SIZE)
            for y in range(tree_end, leaf_end, -TILE_SIZE):
                self.chunk_data_overworld.append(Tile(self.chunk_x, y,
                    TILE_TYPES["leaf"], TEXTURES["leaf"]))

    # Generate an overworld chunk for the sides
    def generate_overworld_chunk_side(self):
        beach_end = HEIGHT-round_tile_size(random.randint(4, 6)*TILE_SIZE)
        for y in range(HEIGHT, beach_end, -TILE_SIZE):
            self.chunk_data_overworld.append(Tile(self.chunk_x, y,
                TILE_TYPES["sand"], TEXTURES["sand"]))

    # Generate an overworld chunk for the far sides
    def generate_overworld_chunk_far_side(self):
        water_end = HEIGHT-(TILE_SIZE*3)
        for y in range(HEIGHT, water_end, -TILE_SIZE):
            self.chunk_data_overworld.append(Tile(self.chunk_x, y,
                TILE_TYPES["water"], TEXTURES["water"]))

    # Generate an underground chunk
    def generate_underground_chunk(self):

        # Generate the top section
        stone_end1 = 0+round_tile_size(random.randint(3, 5)*TILE_SIZE)
        for y in range(0, stone_end1, TILE_SIZE):
            self.chunk_data_underground.append(Tile(self.chunk_x, y,
                TILE_TYPES["stone"], TEXTURES["stone"]))

        # Generate the bottom section
        stone_end2 = HEIGHT-round_tile_size(random.randint(3, 5)*TILE_SIZE)
        for y in range(HEIGHT, stone_end2, -TILE_SIZE):
            self.chunk_data_underground.append(Tile(self.chunk_x, y,
                TILE_TYPES["stone"], TEXTURES["stone"]))


    # Add new underground chunk data
    def add_new_chunk_data_underground(self):
        self.chunk_data_underground.append(self.chunk_x)
        self.generate_underground_chunk()
        underground_data.append(self.chunk_data_underground)

    # Add a new chunk for the far sides
    def add_new_chunk_data_far_side(self):
        self.chunk_data_overworld.append(self.chunk_x)
        self.generate_overworld_chunk_far_side()
        overworld_data.append(self.chunk_data_overworld)

    # Add new chunk data for the sides
    def add_new_chunk_data_side(self):
        self.chunk_data_overworld.append(self.chunk_x)
        self.generate_overworld_chunk_side()
        overworld_data.append(self.chunk_data_overworld)

    # Add chunk data to the world for the center
    def add_new_chunk_data_center(self):
        self.chunk_data_overworld.append(self.chunk_x)
        self.generate_overworld_chunk_center()
        overworld_data.append(self.chunk_data_overworld)


# WorldGenerator class, responsible for finalizing world data
class WorldGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.START_X_CENTER = -2000
        self.END_X_CENTER = 2000

        # Start and end for left side
        self.START_X_LEFT = self.START_X_CENTER-500
        self.END_X_LEFT = self.START_X_CENTER

        # Start and end for right side
        self.START_X_RIGHT = self.END_X_CENTER
        self.END_X_RIGHT = self.END_X_CENTER+500

        # Start and end for far left side
        self.START_X_FAR_LEFT = self.START_X_LEFT-750
        self.END_X_FAR_LEFT = self.START_X_LEFT

        # Start and end for far right side
        self.START_X_FAR_RIGHT = self.END_X_RIGHT
        self.END_X_FAR_RIGHT = self.END_X_RIGHT+750

        # Start and end for underground
        self.UNDER_START_X = -3250
        self.UNDER_END_X = 3250

    # Generate the world
    def generate_world(self):

        # Generate the far left side
        for chunk_x in range(self.START_X_FAR_LEFT, self.END_X_FAR_LEFT, TILE_SIZE):
            chunk = Chunk(chunk_x)
            chunk.add_new_chunk_data_far_side()

        # Generate the left side
        for chunk_x in range(self.START_X_LEFT, self.END_X_LEFT, TILE_SIZE):
            chunk = Chunk(chunk_x)
            chunk.add_new_chunk_data_side()

        # Generate the center
        for chunk_x in range(self.START_X_CENTER, self.END_X_CENTER, TILE_SIZE):
            chunk = Chunk(chunk_x)
            chunk.add_new_chunk_data_center()

        # Generate the right side
        for chunk_x in range(self.START_X_RIGHT, self.END_X_RIGHT, TILE_SIZE):
            chunk = Chunk(chunk_x)
            chunk.add_new_chunk_data_side()

        # Generate the far right side
        for chunk_x in range(self.START_X_FAR_RIGHT, self.END_X_FAR_RIGHT, TILE_SIZE):
            chunk = Chunk(chunk_x)
            chunk.add_new_chunk_data_far_side()

        # Generate the underground portion
        for chunk_x in range(self.UNDER_START_X, self.UNDER_END_X, TILE_SIZE):
            chunk = Chunk(chunk_x)
            chunk.add_new_chunk_data_underground()


# ChunkLoader class, used for rendering chunks
class ChunkLoader(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # Render the current loaded chunks aboveground
    def render_current_loaded_chunks_aboveground(self):
        for chunk in overworld_data:
            for tile in chunk[1:]:
                if tile.x >= 0 and tile.x <= WIDTH:
                    tile.render_tile()

    # Render the current loaded chunks underground
    def render_current_loaded_chunks_underground(self):
        for chunk in underground_data:
            for tile in chunk[1:]:
                if tile.x >= 0 and tile.x <= WIDTH:
                    tile.render_tile()


# Player class, containing all player data
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.chunk_loader = ChunkLoader()
        self.selected_tile = 0
        self.inventory = {
            0: [0, pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameDirtBlock.png"), (17, 17))],
            1: [0, pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameGrassBlock.png"), (17, 17))],
            2: [0, pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameStoneBlock.png"), (17, 17))],
            3: [0, pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameSandBlock.png"), (17, 17))],
            4: [0, pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameWaterBlock.png"), (17, 17))],
            5: [0, pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameWoodBlock.png"), (17, 17))],
            6: [0, pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameLeafBlock.png"), (17, 17))],
        }

    # Loop through the world and change tile positions belowground
    def loop_through_world_belowground(self, x_change, y_change):
        for chunk in underground_data:
            for tile in chunk[1:]:
                tile.update_tile_position(x_change, y_change)

    # Move through the world belowground
    def move_player_belowground(self):
        if key_pressed()[pygame.K_a]:
            self.loop_through_world_belowground(TILE_SIZE, 0)
        if key_pressed()[pygame.K_d]:
            self.loop_through_world_belowground(-TILE_SIZE, 0)

    # Loop through the world and change tile positions aboveground
    def loop_through_world_aboveground(self, x_change, y_change):
        for chunk in overworld_data:
            for tile in chunk[1:]:
                tile.update_tile_position(x_change, y_change)

    # Move through the world aboveground
    def move_player_aboveground(self):
        if key_pressed()[pygame.K_a]:
            self.loop_through_world_aboveground(TILE_SIZE, 0)
        if key_pressed()[pygame.K_d]:
            self.loop_through_world_aboveground(-TILE_SIZE, 0)

    # Render the player's hitbox on the screen
    def render_player_hitbox(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE,
            pygame.Rect(round_tile_size(mouse_pos()[mouse_x]-(TILE_SIZE/2)),
                 round_tile_size(mouse_pos()[mouse_y]-(TILE_SIZE/2)),
                     TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE), 1)

    # Render the player's inventory
    def render_player_inventory(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY_DARK, (3, 218, 22, 142), 0)

        # Positions for inventory items
        item_x = 5
        item_y = 220

        # Render the item "icons"
        for item in self.inventory:
            item_image = self.inventory[item][1]
            screen.blit(item_image, (item_x, item_y))
            item_y += 20

        # Change item_x and item_y
        item_x = 7.5
        item_y = 226.5

        # Render the item counts
        for item in self.inventory:
            item_count = FONT.render(
                "{}".format(self.inventory[item][0]), 1, WHITE)
            screen.blit(item_count, (item_x, item_y))
            item_y += 20

        # Render the selected tile
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY_DARK, (3, 193, 22, 22), 0)
        screen.blit(self.inventory[self.selected_tile][1], (5, 195))

    # Change the selected tile
    def change_selected_tile(self):
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            if self.selected_tile <= len(self.inventory)-2:
                self.selected_tile += 1
            else:
                self.selected_tile = 0

    # Change between underground and aboveground
    def change_aboveground_underground(self):

        # Make aboveground & belowground variables global
        global player_aboveground
        global player_underground

        # Change to belowground
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_q]:
            player_aboveground = False
            player_underground = True

        # Change to aboveground
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_e]:
            player_aboveground = True
            player_underground = False

    # Delete a tile from the world aboveground
    def delete_tile_aboveground(self):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            for chunk in overworld_data:  
                for tile in chunk[1:]:
                    if round_tile_size(mouse_pos()[mouse_x]-(TILE_SIZE/2)) == tile.x and round_tile_size(mouse_pos()[mouse_y]-(TILE_SIZE/2)) == tile.y:
                        if self.inventory[tile.tile_type][0] <= 127:
                            self.inventory[tile.tile_type][0] += 1
                            del overworld_data[overworld_data.index(chunk)][overworld_data[overworld_data.index(chunk)].index(tile)]
                            break

    # Add a tile to the world aboveground
    def add_tile_aboveground(self):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]:
            for chunk in overworld_data:
                if round_tile_size(mouse_pos()[mouse_x]-(TILE_SIZE/2)) == chunk[0]:
                    if self.inventory[self.selected_tile][0] >= 1:
                        self.inventory[self.selected_tile][0] -= 1
                        chunk.append(Tile(
                            round_tile_size(mouse_pos()[mouse_x]-(TILE_SIZE/2)),
                            round_tile_size(mouse_pos()[mouse_y]-(TILE_SIZE/2)),
                            self.selected_tile,
                            pygame.transform.scale(self.inventory[self.selected_tile][1], (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
                        ))
                        break

    # Delete a tile from the world belowground
    def delete_tile_belowground(self):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            for chunk in underground_data:  
                for tile in chunk[1:]:
                    if round_tile_size(mouse_pos()[mouse_x]-(TILE_SIZE/2)) == tile.x and round_tile_size(mouse_pos()[mouse_y]-(TILE_SIZE/2)) == tile.y:
                        if self.inventory[tile.tile_type][0] <= 127:
                            self.inventory[tile.tile_type][0] += 1
                            del underground_data[underground_data.index(chunk)][underground_data[underground_data.index(chunk)].index(tile)]
                            break

    # Add a tile to the world belowground
    def add_tile_belowground(self):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]:
            for chunk in underground_data:
                if round_tile_size(mouse_pos()[mouse_x]-(TILE_SIZE/2)) == chunk[0]:
                    if self.inventory[self.selected_tile][0] >= 1:
                        self.inventory[self.selected_tile][0] -= 1
                        chunk.append(Tile(
                            round_tile_size(mouse_pos()[mouse_x]-(TILE_SIZE/2)),
                            round_tile_size(mouse_pos()[mouse_y]-(TILE_SIZE/2)),
                            self.selected_tile,
                            pygame.transform.scale(self.inventory[self.selected_tile][1], (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
                        ))
                        break


# Game class, where the events are executed
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = Player()
        self.chunk_loader = ChunkLoader()
        self.background = Background()

    # Run all game events
    def run_events(self):
        self.background.render_background()

        # Player aboveground?
        if player_aboveground:
            self.chunk_loader.render_current_loaded_chunks_aboveground()

        # Player underground?
        if player_underground:
            self.chunk_loader.render_current_loaded_chunks_underground()

        # Move player aboveground?
        if player_aboveground:
            self.player.move_player_aboveground()

        # Move player underground?
        if player_underground:
            self.player.move_player_belowground()

        # Other player methods
        self.player.change_selected_tile()
        self.player.render_player_hitbox()
        self.player.render_player_inventory()
        self.player.change_aboveground_underground()

        # Add & delete tiles aboveground?
        if player_aboveground:
            self.player.delete_tile_aboveground()
            self.player.add_tile_aboveground()

        # Add and delete tile belowground?
        if player_underground:
            self.player.delete_tile_belowground()
            self.player.add_tile_belowground()


# Initalize the game
def initalize_game():
    clock.tick(75)
    background = Background()
    generator = WorldGenerator()
    generator.generate_world()


# Print game debug data
def print_debug_data():
    if debug_game_data:
        for chunk in overworld_data:
            for tile in chunk[1:]:
                print tile.tile_type, tile.x, tile.y


# Main program loop where all game events are executed
def main_program_loop():
    game = Game()
    while True:
        game.run_events()
        pygame.display.update()

        # Check if the user wants to quit
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)


# Start the main program loop
if __name__ == "__main__":
    initalize_game()
    print_debug_data()
    main_program_loop()
```

*For those who are curious, the tile textures can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku6F9.png).*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things that could be improved upon:

---

> ```
> TEXTURES = {
>     "dirt": pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameDirtBlock.png"), (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)),
>     "grass": pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameGrassBlock.png"), (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)),
>     "stone": pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameStoneBlock.png"), (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)),
>     "sand": pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameSandBlock.png"), (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)),
>     "water": pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameWaterBlock.png"), (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)),
>     "wood": pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameWoodBlock.png"), (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)),
>     "leaf": pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameLeafBlock.png"), (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)),
> }
> ```

A few things here:

- There's no need to wrap the actual texture title with `game*Block`: `./images/*.png` is fine.
- All the lines are basically the same except for the texture title, you could probably loop over this if you wanted, or move the `pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(), (TITLE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))` into a function.

---

> ```
>     def render_background(self):
>         if player_aboveground:
>             screen.fill(self.SKY_COLOR)
>         if player_underground:
>             screen.fill(self.UNDERGROUND_SKY_COLOR)
> ```

Shouldn't `if player_underground` be `elif`? You can't be in both places at once.

---

> ```
>     self.START_X_LEFT = self.START_X_CENTER-500
>     self.END_X_LEFT = self.START_X_CENTER
>
>     # Start and end for right side
>     self.START_X_RIGHT = self.END_X_CENTER
>     self.END_X_RIGHT = self.END_X_CENTER+500
>
>     # Start and end for far left side
>     self.START_X_FAR_LEFT = self.START_X_LEFT-750
>     self.END_X_FAR_LEFT = self.START_X_LEFT
>
>     # Start and end for far right side
>     self.START_X_FAR_RIGHT = self.END_X_RIGHT
>     self.END_X_FAR_RIGHT = self.END_X_RIGHT+750
> ```

Where's the spacing in between `self.* + val`?

---

> ```
>     self.inventory = {
>         0: [0, pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameDirtBlock.png"), (17, 17))],
>         1: [0, pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameGrassBlock.png"), (17, 17))],
>         2: [0, pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameStoneBlock.png"), (17, 17))],
>         3: [0, pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameSandBlock.png"), (17, 17))],
>         4: [0, pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameWaterBlock.png"), (17, 17))],
>         5: [0, pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameWoodBlock.png"), (17, 17))],
>         6: [0, pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("./images/gameLeafBlock.png"), (17, 17))],
>     }
> ```

Really?

1. You should cast expelliarmus on the magic number `17`!
2. `ArrayPosition`s are bad keys. In fact, useless.
3. I'm not familiar with `pygame`, but couldn't you just transform the `TEXTURES` instead?

---

> ```
>     for chunk_x in range(self.START_X_FAR_LEFT, self.END_X_FAR_LEFT, TILE_SIZE):
>         chunk = Chunk(chunk_x)
>         chunk.add_new_chunk_data_far_side()
>
>     # Generate the left side
>     for chunk_x in range(self.START_X_LEFT, self.END_X_LEFT, TILE_SIZE):
>         chunk = Chunk(chunk_x)
>         chunk.add_new_chunk_data_side()
>
>     # Generate the center
>     for chunk_x in range(self.START_X_CENTER, self.END_X_CENTER, TILE_SIZE):
>         chunk = Chunk(chunk_x)
>         chunk.add_new_chunk_data_center()
>
>     # Generate the right side
>     for chunk_x in range(self.START_X_RIGHT, self.END_X_RIGHT, TILE_SIZE):
>         chunk = Chunk(chunk_x)
>         chunk.add_new_chunk_data_side()
>
>     # Generate the far right side
>     for chunk_x in range(self.START_X_FAR_RIGHT, self.END_X_FAR_RIGHT, TILE_SIZE):
>         chunk = Chunk(chunk_x)
>         chunk.add_new_chunk_data_far_side()
>
>     # Generate the underground portion
>     for chunk_x in range(self.UNDER_START_X, self.UNDER_END_X, TILE_SIZE):
>         chunk = Chunk(chunk_x)
>         chunk.add_new_chunk_data_underground()
> ```

**DRY** this a bit.

---

> ```
> def initalize_game():
>     clock.tick(75)
>     background = Background()
>     generator = WorldGenerator()
>     generator.generate_world()
> ```

Is there any reason to assign `background` and `generator`?

```
    Background()
    WorldGenerator().generate_world()
```

---

Why do the comments in `run_events` have question marks on the end`?`

> ```
> # Player aboveground?
> ```

---

Also in `run_events`:

> ```
>     # Player aboveground?
>     if player_aboveground:
>         self.chunk_loader.render_current_loaded_chunks_aboveground()
>
>     # Player underground?
>     if player_underground:
>         self.chunk_loader.render_current_loaded_chunks_underground()
>
>     # Move player aboveground?
>     if player_aboveground:
>         self.player.move_player_aboveground()
>
>     # Move player underground?
>     if player_underground:
>         self.player.move_player_belowground()
> ```

Why are these seperate?

```
    if player_aboveground:
        self.chunk_loader.render_current_loaded_chunks_aboveground()
        self.player.move_player_aboveground()

    elif player_underground:
        self.chunk_loader.render_current_loaded_chunks_underground()
        self.player.move_player_belowground()
```

---

On a related note to above:

> ```
>     if player_aboveground:
>         self.chunk_loader.render_current_loaded_chunks_aboveground()
>         self.player.move_player_aboveground()
>
>     elif player_underground:
>         self.chunk_loader.render_current_loaded_chunks_underground()
>         self.player.move_player_belowground()
> ```

- **Above**: `player_aboveground`, `*chunks_aboveground()`, `*move_player_aboveground()`
- **Under**: `player_underground`, `*loaded_chunks_underground()`, `move_player_belowground()`

All the `above` ones use `above`, but all the `under` ones are not the same, one is `below`. IMHO, below sounds better (*Linguistically*) than under, but, the issue is that they should all be consistent.